# Refresh child component from parent component in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a form in parent component (in a modal window). When I submit the form, I want the new data reflected on the current route.

The following function is triggered on form submission

```
  submitAppointment(data) {

      this.dataService.postAppointment(data).subscribe( (res:any) => {
        if(res.status == 0) {
          alert(res.msg);
          $('#addAppointment').modal('hide');
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/schedule']);

        } else {
          alert(res.msg);
        }
      } )

  }
```

I have enabled navigation to same route using the following code

in child.component.ts

```
constructor(private router:Router, private dataService: DataService) { 
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function() {
        return false;
    };
  }
```

in app-routing.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
}
```

Now this is working. But in the child component, I'm listing content in tabs. Each tab represents a date. Clicking on a tab will fetch data assosiated with that date (appointments for the selected date). Now what happens is that, if I click on the second or third tab and then add an appointment using the form, after refresh the selection goes back to first tab (just like a full page reload would do). Instead of this, I want to see the new data updated on the same tab ie, I want to see the newly entered data in the column without refreshing the entire component. How do I do this?

Code below is to display tabs ( dates starting from today to a week)

```
<div class="top-row-right">
    <ul>
      <li class="date-selector"  *ngFor="let d of data.dates" (click)="loadDate(d.date)" 
        [ngClass]="date== d.date ? 'active' : '' ">
          <Strong>{{d.day}}</Strong>
          <small>{{d.date | date : "dd MMM" }}</small>
      </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

and the appointments for selected day are displayed with this

```
<tr *ngFor="let c of data.cArray">
  <td class="table-docname">
    <div class="doc-box">
      <div class="doc-pic">
          <img src="../../../assets/img/user-placeholder.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="doc-details">
          <small>ID {{c.id}}</small>
          <strong>{{c.name}}</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
  </td>

  <td *ngFor="let slot of c.slots">
      <div class="patient-box patient-normal" *ngIf="slot.status == 1">
          <small>ID {{slot.id}}</small>
          <strong>{{slot.patient_name}}</strong>

      </div>

  </td>

</tr>
```

Comment: for that you use show and hide html so it will reload data without refresh

Comment: You must be closing the modal on a successful http response. you can manually add that tab in you data structure maintaing it rather that refreshing the page and getting the data again